# Menu hover does not work

Tags: html, css

I'm new to css and html and because I want to learn, I have started to recreate a website. I don't know what I'm doing wrong, but when I hover to the menu buttons, nothing happens and I don't see the pointer cursor, even though I specified it in the code. Thanks in advance for your help!

```css
@charset "utf-8";

/*
* {
   outline: 1px solid red !important; 
}*/


* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
 font-family: "open sans","HelveticaNeue-Light","Helvetica Neue Light","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,"Lucida Grande",sans-serif;
 font-weight:300;
 margin: 0;
 padding:0;
 border: 0;
 font-size: 13px;
 line-height: 18px;
 color: #333333;
 display:block;
 vertical-align:baseline;
 min-height: 100%;
 min-width: 1200px;
 position:relative;

}

.grid {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1903px;
    width: 100%;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 outline: 0;
 position:relative;
}

.row {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    display: flex;

}

.col-1 {
    width: 8.33%;
}

.col-2 {
    width: 16.66%;
}

.col-3 {
    width: 25%;
}

.col-4 {
    width: 33.33%;
}

.col-5 {
    width: 41.66%;
}

.col-6 {
    width: 50%;
}

.col-7 {
    width: 58.33%;
}

.col-8 {
    width: 66.66%;
}

.col-9 {
    width: 75%;
}

.col-10 {
    width: 83.33%;
}

.col-11 {
    width: 91.66%;
}

.col-12 {
    width: 100%;
}

.header {
 background-image:  url(http://du1frgvkr39c.cloudfront.net/assets/landing-page/landingpage-c21ba89811cc1724fbe9abb71227cd10.jpg);
 background-size: cover;
 max-width: 100%;
 position:relative;
 height: 841px;
 display:block;
}

.header::after {
 content: "";
    background: rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.2);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
/*
header > * {
    z-index: 10;
}*/

.brand {
 position: relative;
}

#logo {
 position: absolute;
 top: 20px;
 left: 20px;
 cursor: pointer;
 box-shadow:none;

 }
 
.navBar {
 float: right;
 position: absolute;
 right: 0;
 display: inline;
 padding: 10px;
 margin: 10px 0;
}

.no-btn {
 color: #fff;
 display:inline;
}

/*
.no-btn li {
 display: inline;
    float: left;
    margin: 55px 0;
}*/

.no-btn a {
 color: #fff;
 text-decoration:none;
 list-style:none;
 display: inline;
 margin-left: 20px;
 font-weight:bold;
 font-size: 14px;
}

.navBar .no-btn a:hover {
 background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.5);
 color: red;
 cursor:pointer;
 
}

.signin {
 color: #fff;
 display: inline;
 margin-left: 10px;
 margin-top: 30px;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.signin a {
 color:  #fff;
 text-decoration:none;
 list-style:none;
 display: inline;
 font-weight:bold;
 font-size: 14px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 border: 2px solid #fff;
 border-radius: 2px;
 padding: 7px 10px;
 cursor:pointer;
}


.navBar .btn a:hover {
 background-color: #FFF;
 color: #333;
 cursor: pointer;
 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="eng">
<head >
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>The Travel Bucket List Community — BucketListly</title>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome-4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<div class="grid">
    <div class="header">
     <div class="row">
         <div class="col-1">
             <div class="brand">
                  <a href="http://www.bucketlistly.com/" id="logo">
                     <img alt="Logo Icon White" src="img/logo-icon-white-2bae76747b5ea1996d4ec47a93e92ee1.png"/>
                  </a> 
               </div> 
               
               <div class="col-4">
                   <div class="navBar">
                   <ul>
                     <li class="no-btn"><a href="/about" title="About">About</a></li>
                        <li class="no-btn"><a href="/faq" title="FAQ">FAQ</a></li>
                        <li class="no-btn"><a href="/blog" title="Blog">Blog</a></li>
                        <li class="signin"><a href="/categories" class="btn" title="Ideas"><i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                        <span>Bucket List Ideas</span></a></li>
                        <li class="signin"><a href="/signin" title="Sign in">Sign in</a></li>
                      </ul>
                  </div>
               </div>  
            </div>            
        </div> 
     </div>                            
</div>   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: its because of the CSS you have written over `.header:after` for giving that light background color over that image. Best and Quick practice: Give that shade over the image using Photoshop or some image editing tool. and remove that code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use before instead of after:

```css
@charset "utf-8";

/*
* {
   outline: 1px solid red !important; 
}*/


* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
 font-family: "open sans","HelveticaNeue-Light","Helvetica Neue Light","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,"Lucida Grande",sans-serif;
 font-weight:300;
 margin: 0;
 padding:0;
 border: 0;
 font-size: 13px;
 line-height: 18px;
 color: #333333;
 display:block;
 vertical-align:baseline;
 min-height: 100%;
 min-width: 1200px;
 position:relative;

}

.grid {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1903px;
    width: 100%;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 outline: 0;
 position:relative;
}

.row {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    display: flex;

}

.col-1 {
    width: 8.33%;
}

.col-2 {
    width: 16.66%;
}

.col-3 {
    width: 25%;
}

.col-4 {
    width: 33.33%;
}

.col-5 {
    width: 41.66%;
}

.col-6 {
    width: 50%;
}

.col-7 {
    width: 58.33%;
}

.col-8 {
    width: 66.66%;
}

.col-9 {
    width: 75%;
}

.col-10 {
    width: 83.33%;
}

.col-11 {
    width: 91.66%;
}

.col-12 {
    width: 100%;
}

.header {
 background-image:  url(http://du1frgvkr39c.cloudfront.net/assets/landing-page/landingpage-c21ba89811cc1724fbe9abb71227cd10.jpg);
 background-size: cover;
 max-width: 100%;
 position:relative;
 height: 841px;
 display:block;
}

.header::before {
 content: "";
    background: rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.2);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
/*
header > * {
    z-index: 10;
}*/

.brand {
 position: relative;
}

#logo {
 position: absolute;
 top: 20px;
 left: 20px;
 cursor: pointer;
 box-shadow:none;

 }
 
.navBar {
 float: right;
 position: absolute;
 right: 0;
 display: inline;
 padding: 10px;
 margin: 10px 0;
}

.no-btn {
 color: #fff;
 display:inline;
}

/*
.no-btn li {
 display: inline;
    float: left;
    margin: 55px 0;
}*/

.no-btn a {
 color: #fff;
 text-decoration:none;
 list-style:none;
 display: inline;
 margin-left: 20px;
 font-weight:bold;
 font-size: 14px;
}

.navBar .no-btn a:hover {
 background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.5);
 color: red;
 cursor:pointer;
 
}

.signin {
 color: #fff;
 display: inline;
 margin-left: 10px;
 margin-top: 30px;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.signin a {
 color:  #fff;
 text-decoration:none;
 list-style:none;
 display: inline;
 font-weight:bold;
 font-size: 14px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 border: 2px solid #fff;
 border-radius: 2px;
 padding: 7px 10px;
 cursor:pointer;
}


.navBar .btn a:hover {
 background-color: #FFF;
 color: #333;
 cursor: pointer;
 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="eng">
<head >
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>The Travel Bucket List Community — BucketListly</title>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome-4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<div class="grid">
    <div class="header">
     <div class="row">
         <div class="col-1">
             <div class="brand">
                  <a href="http://www.bucketlistly.com/" id="logo">
                     <img alt="Logo Icon White" src="img/logo-icon-white-2bae76747b5ea1996d4ec47a93e92ee1.png"/>
                  </a> 
               </div> 
               
               <div class="col-4">
                   <div class="navBar">
                   <ul>
                     <li class="no-btn"><a href="/about" title="About">About</a></li>
                        <li class="no-btn"><a href="/faq" title="FAQ">FAQ</a></li>
                        <li class="no-btn"><a href="/blog" title="Blog">Blog</a></li>
                        <li class="signin"><a href="/categories" class="btn" title="Ideas"><i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                        <span>Bucket List Ideas</span></a></li>
                        <li class="signin"><a href="/signin" title="Sign in">Sign in</a></li>
                      </ul>
                  </div>
               </div>  
            </div>            
        </div> 
     </div>                            
</div>   
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
.navBar ul li a:hover {
    background-color: #FFF;
    color: #333;
    cursor: pointer;

}
```